# Why when I go and view someones user profile (localhost/{{user}}/) it alters my base.html file?

Tags: python, django

I've recently been trying to add a user profile view to my HackerNews Clone. When you go to localhost/{{userame}} it takes you to that page, and tells you the stories that person has most recently upvoted/submitted.

**Here's the problem:** I log in successfully. My base.html file basically contains a navbar, that returns the logged in username in the right hand corner (like most websites).

Now, when I go to view someone's profile, i.e. localhost/{{username}}, that {{username}} variable feeds into my base.html which then changes who shows up on that navbar as logged in.

How can I prevent this from happening? Here is my code:

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
<head>
    <title>NewsFeed </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static "css/master.css" %}">

    {% block head %}

    {% endblock head %}
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "content">
        <div id = "header">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <div id = "user-info"><a href = "/{{ user.username }}">{{ user.username }}</a> | <a href = "/story/">sumbit</a> | <a href = "/logout/">logout</a></div>

            {% else %}

                <div id = "user-info"><a href = "/login/">Login</a></div>
                <div id = "user-info"><a href = "/register/">Sign Up</a></div>

            {% endif %}
            <div id = "site-title"><h1><a href = "/">newsfeed</a></h1></div>
        </div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request, username):
    template = 'stories/profile.html'
    user = User.objects.get(username = username)
    return render(request, template, {
        'user': user,
        })
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'stories.views.profile'),
```

** profile.html **

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load story_extras %}

{% block content %}
    <h2 style = "margin-left:20px"> {{ user.username}} </h2>

    <ol>
    Need to add in liked stories of particular user here. Working on it....
    </ol>
{% endblock content %}
```

NOTE: I haven't yet implemented the entire profile page. Just stuck on this issue at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user from your view is clashing with the logged in user from the auth context processor. You can fix it by choosing a different variable name for the user in your view.

```
return render(request, template, {
    'other_user': user,
})
```

Then in your template

```
{{ other_user }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are showing the `username` using which account have logged in. So, it will keep showing logged in username unless you log out of that.

Comment: Do you know how I could go about fixing it?

Comment: you may want to extract the username from url and print that on template!